# Proof that these two definitions are equivalent

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Where can I find a proof of or how can I prove that these two definitions are equivalent?

Definition 1: The Lie algebra of a Lie group $G \subset GL_n$ is the tangent space at $I$.

Definition 2: The Lie algebra of a Lie group $G \subset GL_n$ is all elements $g\in G$ with the property that for all $t \in \mathbb R$ the element $e^{t g}$ is also in $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition 2 is incorrect: In general, the Lie algebra of $G\subset GL_n$ is not a subset of $G$ (or even of $GL_n$). For example, the zero matrix is an element of the Lie algebra, but it's not an element of $GL_n$.

In place of Definition 2, you could write

Definition 2$'$: The Lie algebra of a Lie group $G \subset GL_n$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices $g$ with the property that for all $t \in \mathbb R$ the element $e^{t g}$ is also in $G$.

The equivalence of this and Definition 1 should be proved in most elementary books about Lie groups. You can also find it in my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (chapters 7 and 20).

Comment: Could you point out the page number of the proof? I couldn't even find the two definitions in your book.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said Chapters 8 and 20. The definition of the Lie algebra of $G$ that I give is different from both of yours: in my book, it's the set of left-invariant vector fields on the group. Using that definition together with Theorem 8.37, Proposition 8.41, and Proposition 20.9, you can prove the result you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have one last question: The definition of Lie algebra ''Definition 2' '' -- it is also applicable to $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ not just $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, or is it not?

Comment: Yes. And it's actually applicable much more generally: Proposition 20.9 in my book shows that if $H$ is any Lie subgroup of a Lie group $G$, then the Lie algebra of $H$ is the set of all $X$ in the Lie algebra of $G$ such that $\operatorname{exp} tX\in H$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$.