# Where is my mistake: determining the Lie algebra of complex orthogonal matrices

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I tried to determine the Lie algebra of $O(3, \mathbb C)$ but I think there is a mistake but I can't find it.

Here is my work:

Let $\mathfrak o$ denote the Lie algebra of $O(3, \mathbb C)$. The matrices in $O(3,\mathbb C)$ are those of determinant $\pm 1$. Hence $g \in \mathfrak o$ if and only if $e^{gt}$ has determinant $\pm 1$ if and only if $t \cdot \mathrm{trace}(g) $ is equal to zero or equal to $\pi i$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ if and only if $\mathrm{trace}(g) = 0$.

That is, the case $t \cdot \mathrm{trace}(g)= i \pi$ is never satisfied because $t$ varies over $\mathbb R$. But then this would imply that the Lie algebra of $O(3, \mathbb C)$ equals the Lie algebra of $SL_3(\mathbb C)$ by the same argument.

Comment: The issue is that that's not what $O(3,\Bbb C)$ is.

Comment: Your error is that having determinant plus or minus 1 is necessary but not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A:(-1,1)\to U(n)$ be a differentiable mapping such that $A(0) = I$.  We know that for each $t \in (-1,1)$ that $A(t)A^\dagger(t) = I$.  Take the derivative of both sides

\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dt} A(t) A^\dagger(t) \;\; =\;\; \dot{A}(t)A^\dagger(t) + A(t)\dot{A}^\dagger(t) \;\; =\;\; 0.
\end{equation*}

Now evaluate this at $t = 0$

$$
\left . \frac{d}{dt} A(t) A^\dagger(t) \right |_{t=0} \;\; =\;\; \dot{A}(0)A^\dagger(0) + A(0)\dot{A}^\dagger(0) \;\; =\;\; \dot{A}(0) + \dot{A}^\dagger(0) \;\; =\;\; 0
$$

where we use the fact that $A(0) = A^\dagger(0) = I$.  This proves that $\dot{A}(0) = - \dot{A}^\dagger(0)$ so any tangent vector (or matrix rather) at the identity is a skew-Hermitian matrix.  Therefore

$$
\mathfrak{u}(n) \;\; =\;\; \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) \; | \; A = - A^\dagger\}.
$$

Comment: I see you are using the tangent space definition of Lie algebra. Is there a similarly short argument using the exponential map definition?

Comment: What is the exponential map definition of a Lie algebra?  I know the Lie algebra is the tangent space at the identity, and that Exp:$\mathfrak{o}(n, \mathbb{C}) \to O(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: An equivalent definition using the exponential map is: If $G \subset GL_n$ is a Lie group then its Lie algebra consist of all $g \in M_n$ such that $e^{tg}\in G$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. I admit that as I typed this definition it just now made me wonder if this definition only works for real matrices. But maybe not?

Comment: Also see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127659/proof-that-these-two-definitions-are-equivalent).

Comment: I've been thinking about this for a while and have come stuck to this place:  I need to show that if $e^{gt}$ and $e^{g^\dagger t}$ commute then $g$ and $g^\dagger$ commute, so that we can write $e^{gt} e^{g^\dagger t} = e^{(g+g^\dagger)t} = I$.